# What's the difference between panic("error_msg") and panic(error.New("error_msg")?

Tags: go

Considering I'm using the original "errors" go package.

And, the difference between panic(11) and panic("11")?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`panic`](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#panic) is defined as `func panic(v interface{})`, calling `panic(anything)` will print the the string representation of `anything` then the stacktrace of the calling function.

Only difference is, if you use [`recover`](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#recover), you will be able to access whatever you passed to panic, for [example](http://play.golang.org/p/5tIMqjogtt):

```
func main() {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            if n, ok := err.(int); ok && n == 11 {
                fmt.Println("got 11!")
            }
        }
    }()
    panic(11)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`panic("error_msg")` and `panic("11")` panic a string while `panic(error.New("error_msg")` panics an error and `panic(11)` panics an integer.

If you do not handle these panics with `recover` during `defer` than it won't matter which you use, all will print the "error_msg" or "11".